# Check if firebase query (for firebase options) returns empty (does not exist)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am using a filter query for a firebaseRecyclerAdapter (firebaseOptions).

Since I am using a searchView the recycler updates with every typed letter, if the query exists.

The problem is that I would like to clear the recycler if the query does not exist.

How can I add a check to see if the query is successful or not?

I am implementing a search, if the query exists I populate the recyclerview, if the query does not exist I want to clear the recyclerview.

```
public void fireSearch(String queryInput) {
        String start = queryInput.toUpperCase(), end = queryInput.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff";
    Log.d("myTag", start + " " + end);
    firebaseQuery = databaseReference.orderByKey().startAt(start).endAt(end);
    searchRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BusinessDetails> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<BusinessDetails>()
                    .setQuery(firebaseQuery, BusinessDetails.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                    .build();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried in code for that?

Comment: @AlexMamo I have edited my post. It does exactly what I wrote to be honest.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: I want to check if the query exists or not before passing it on to the firebase adapter because when the query doesn't exist then I want to clear the recyclerview.

Comment: @AlexMamo I updated my question, hopefully it is simple enough to understand now.

Comment: If the query has no results, the `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` will already clear the existing data. There is no need for you to handle this case yourself.

Comment: I have checked it with logs, the adapter does not update. The existing data remains until a new query (which is successful) replaces the data.

Comment: Sorry I have been busy, tested it now. It works thanks

Comment: @frank similarly, it is also helpful for me to know why my question has been down voted. In that way I can ask better questions next time.

Comment: Hey Emmanuel. Agreed that would be useful. I wasn't the downvoter so can't be certain, but the lack of code in your initial post tends to attract quick downvotes.

Comment: Alright, I will try to add so code in the future. However sometimes, it seems that words are enough. Thanks again for the solution Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query has no results, the `FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter` will already clear the existing data. There is no need for you to handle this case yourself.

If you want to do some additional work when there is no data, you can override the `onDataChanged`  method in your adapter class.

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(options) {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        // Called each time there is a new data snapshot. You may want to use this method
        // to hide a loading spinner or check for the "no documents" state and update your UI.
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DatabaseError e) {
        // Called when there is an error getting data. You may want to update
        // your UI to display an error message to the user.
        // ...
    }
};
```

Also see the FirebaseUI documentation on [data and error events](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#data-and-error-events), where I got the above code from.